# performance testing - test:profile vs test:benchmark, wall time vs process time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to performance testing on rails. Can somebody explain the difference between wall time and process time? More importantly what is the difference between the time results that come from test:benchmark and test:profile. There is clearly a major difference, which I haven't gleaned from the docs. A few facts:

When I run rake test:benchmark, I get:

```
EditorTest#test_augment_large_doc (618 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 554 ms
              memory: 0.00 KB
             objects: 0
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 0.00 ms
```

When I run rake test:profile, I get:

```
EditorTest#test_augment_large_doc (617 ms warmup)
        process_time: 1.74 sec
              memory: unsupported
             objects: unsupported
```

I have read:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#generating-performance-tests
- http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/

... but I still don't understand the fundamental difference between these types of performance tests and why the times differ so much.

A couple more things: when I tail my development log, I get a time typically a bit higher (.1 secs) than the wall time from test:benchmark. And, when I look at XHR request times in firebug or chrome, I get a time typically .3 secs higher.

Thanks in advance!

[edit]

hmmm... no responses. Any comments? Is this a tool rails developers frequently use? Is the difference irrelevant for the optimization process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, wall time is just as it sounds, the number of seconds that elapsed during the test. Process time is a little different and is a measure of how much of the CPU(s)' time was spent executing the program.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time

In general the difference between benchmarking and profiling has to do with the same distinction. Benchmarking is a simple process of running a bunch of code a number of times and seeing how long it takes.

Profiling is more detailed and can show you how long was spent in different sections of your code, including the number of calls to all methods in the stack. The time taken to run a complete profile isn't meant to be an indication of performance, rather, it will show you the relative performance of different sections of code in your app.

Comment: thanks. I was hoping to find out why it takes 2-3 times longer. any ideas there?

Comment: @joshs profiling will always be slower because it involves running the profiling code as well as your own. In order to figure out how long is spent in each function the profiler must insert itself and watch the stack which slows things down by a constant amount. The relative speed of each section of code should still be relevant, though.